# Get mail address from iPhone/iPad setting area through Xcode

Tags: ios, email-address

I am trying to get email id and other details from iPhone/iPad setting area to my code using objective c. Any suggestion would appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question you want to get personal data from the user. For this you need to call the AdressBook API:

[AdressBook API Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html)

Comment: No,I am trying to get values from configured email account in device. Say for example if i configure a gmail account in my device so i want that mail id and other details in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Here is working example. It loads all emails and full names to passed array. Tailor this code in a way you need, for example, you could find some specific contact and get all info from it.

```
- (NSMutableArray *)loadContactsFromAB:(NSMutableArray *)contacts
{
        ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
        CFArrayRef allPeople = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
        CFIndex nPeople = ABAddressBookGetPersonCount(addressBook);

        for (int i = 0 ; i < nPeople ; i++ ) {
                ABRecordRef person = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allPeople, i);
                NSString *firstName = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
                NSString *lastName = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonLastNameProperty);

                NSString *fullName;

                if (firstName && lastName) {
                        fullName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", firstName, lastName];
                } else {
                        if (firstName) {
                                fullName = [NSString stringWithString:firstName];
                        } else if (lastName) {
                                fullName = [NSString stringWithString:lastName];
                        } else {
                                continue;
                        }
                }

                NSString *email = nil;
                ABMultiValueRef emails = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);

                if (emails) {
                        NSArray *emailAddresses = [(NSArray *)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(emails) autorelease];
                        if (emailAddresses && [emailAddresses count] > 0)
                                email = [emailAddresses objectAtIndex:0];
                        CFRelease(emails);
                }
                if (email) {
                        NSDictionary *contact = [NSDictionary
                                                 dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:fullName, @"name",
                                                 email, @"email", nil];
                        [self addContact:contacts contact:contact];
                }
                if (firstName)
                        CFRelease(firstName);
                if (lastName)
                        CFRelease(lastName);
        }

        CFRelease(allPeople);
        CFRelease(addressBook);
        return contacts;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for prompt answer, But I want to get the details of configured email account in device. Say for example i configure a gmail account in my device, so i want to get mail address and other details in the Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot get the default email in settings, it will handle only by mfmailcomposeviewcontroller